# tmux prefix keyboard shortcut

Tags: tmux

How do I change the `tmux` prefix keyboard shortcut from `ctrl+B` to `space+B` while, by default, the space button has a command?

Answer (score 1):

From tmux man page:

> tmux allows a command to be bound to most keys, with or without a pre-fix key.  When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to ‘Z’).  Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with ‘M-’.

Which means you can bind Ctrl and Alt as prefix keys - not space. Actually, I don't know any app that let's you bind space as a prefix key, but please enlighten me.

To bind another key as tmux prefix key, add the following to .tmux.conf (for Alt+X as prefix key):

```
set -g prefix M-x
bind M-x send-prefix
```

Comment: Well, now that there is no way to set the space, how do I set the Alt and x + % buttons to halve the screen vertically?
Alt + x + %

Comment: Are you using Alt+X as tmux prefix key then? Answer edited above.

Comment: My tmux version is tmux 3.0a
But I did not find a file called .tmux.conf
Can this method >>(set -g prefix M-x
bind M-x send-prefix)<< be adjusted by typing <command prompt> in tmux itself?

Comment: Yes I believe so. But maybe you have to create the .tmux.conf file first if it's not in your user dir, makes things much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've set mine to `Ctrl-Space`. This works really well. I imagine other combinations with Space will work as long as it's the second character in the chain.

In your config you can

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-Space
bind Space send-prefix
```

This will:

1. Unbind the default `C-b`prefix
2. Set `C-Space` to the new prefix
3. And ensure any presses to Space get passed to the active pane